# Load Django Form Object with data from Model instance already "loaded"

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following type of template in Django:

```
    <form .... >
      <label class="control-label" for="id_quantity">Quantiy</label>
      {{ form.quantity }}

      <label class="control-label" for="id_title">Quantiy</label>
      {{ form.title}}

    </form>
```

The view contains a ModelForm object in its context from which the "form" variable in the template is derived.

Often, you can pass a form that is bound to data like request.POST. How do I load a form that is bound to the data of a specific instance of a model? Is there any special syntax?

Comment: `MyForm(instance=currentModel)` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options here:

```
MyModelForm(instance=myInstanceModel)
MyModelForm(initial={ "my": "initial-data" })
```

Comment: What is the data type of "myInstanceModel"

Comment: Is the model that you are going to load in the form