# how to prepopulate a normal form with values from model instance

Tags: django

I have seen thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896096/load-django-form-object-with-data-from-model-instance-already-loaded I think it is for modelforms

Can I create a form with data from model instance

```
blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blogid)
form = BlogForm(instance=blog)
```

here BlogForm is a normal form,

If not how can prepopulate the form with values from the model instance

Comment: Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: @Davit Tovmasyan, Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initial` keyword argument. Here is an example.

```
blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blogid)
form = BlogForm(initial={'title': blog.title})
```